# Unable to get AppPackage and AppActivity

Tags: automation, appium, adb, appium-android

I know that we use adb shell and then dumpsys window windows | grep -E ‘mCurrentFocus’ to find the appPackage and appActivity using adb commands. But when I open an app and run this command I'm not getting anything.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Don't use images, just formatted text for the output of commands

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano i didn't get you

Comment: replace your PNG and use text

Answer (score 1):

Using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) you can just run

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
print(ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()[0].getTopActivityName())
```

and will print something like

```
com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```